# React.js function component's button onClick handler only works once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-dom

My `pages/index.js` :

```js
import Flyout from '../components/flyout'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const [flyouts, setFlyouts] = useState(<></>)

  const [testFlyout, setTestFlyout] = useState('')
  function showTestFlyout() {
```

**This statement only works once.**

```js
    setFlyouts(<Flyout>{testFlyout}</Flyout>)
```

```js
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input value={testFlyout} onChange={function (event) {
        setTestFlyout(event.target.value)
      }} />
      <button onClick={showTestFlyout}>popup</button>
      {flyouts}
    </>
  )
}
```

My `components/flyout.js` :

```js
import styles from './flyout.module.css'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { useState } from 'react';

function Flyout({ title, children }) {
    const [flyoutClassName, setFlyoutClassName] = useState(styles.flyout)

    var closeFlyout = () => {
```

**This works only once, too:**

```js
        setFlyoutClassName(`${styles.flyout} ${styles.closedFlyout}`)
```

```js
    }

    const [flyout, setFlyout] = useState(
        <div className={flyoutClassName}>
            <div>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <button onClick={closeFlyout}>&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div>{children}</div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <>{flyout}</>
    );
}

function showFlyout(...) {
    ...
}

export default Flyout
export { showFlyout, Flyout }
```

This web app is based on React.js, and I'm trying to popup different flyouts that contains the value of the input, but the handle only works on my first click, and it doesn't works whenever I click it after my first click.

So why does all the `setState()` work only once?

Comment: It runs always, but no state change, and that excause no DOM change. Put some `console.log("RUN")` in that functions

Comment: When you click next time does event propagates to your child component or not?

Comment: Remember setState is async in nature. Don't expect a state change immediately after updating the state.